# SubQuery vs TheGraph for blockchain data

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, thegraph, thegraph.com

Within Ethereum blockchain ecosystem TheGraph https://thegraph.com/ became almost standard solution to build GraphQL access to blockchain data (indexed in PostgreSQL)

SubQuery https://www.subquery.network/ does the same but for Polkadot chain.

What are main differences between them? What can be reused when redeploying smart contracts to Polkadot chain?

Comment: There are no "Polkatdot smart contracts" so there is that. Polkatdot is just a security layer for different blockchains. Also looks like Subquery the project exist only as a name - they don't have anything build yet.